# LaunchAgent Jenkins fail installing CocoaPods using plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cocoapods, launch-agent

I'm trying to set up a jenkins CI server to build some iOS and Android code.
I have it building some of my projects using the Xcode plugin and some shell scripts, mainly `pod install`.
From there, I tried to remove this shell script and use the CocoaPods plugin, to do things properly. It worked at first.

Unfortunately, that was when running jenkins manually, from the CLI.
I now set up a LaunchAgent and the CocoaPods plugin fails without any error or helpful indication in the console output.

```
[workspace] $ pod repo update
Build step 'Update CocoaPods' marked build as failure
```

ps command result:

```
501 16899   304   0  4:29PM ??         3:15.29 /usr/bin/java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -jar /usr/local/opt/jenkins/libexec/jenkins.war --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --httpPort=8080
```

When working, ps command result:

```
501 23983 22213   0  6:33PM ttys003    0:09.11 /usr/bin/java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -jar /usr/local/opt/jenkins/libexec/jenkins.war --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --httpPort=8080
```

Should I just drop the plugin, or is there some specificity on the LaunchAgent I do not know about ?

LaunchAgent homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
      <string>-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/jenkins/libexec/jenkins.war</string>
      <string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>
      <string>--httpPort=8080</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```